# Unit Test Vertx AsyncHandler with Mockito

Tags: unit-testing, junit, mockito, vert.x

I am trying yo unit test my method which internally calls DB which I am trying to mock and want to return the response but getting an error.

```
 public void processAlert(JsonObject requestInput, Handler<AsyncResult<JsonObject>> handler) {
        JsonObject jobInput = new JsonObject().put("requestInput", requestInput);
        dbService.saveJobDetails(jobInput, readyHandler -> {
            if (readyHandler.succeeded()) {
                handler.handle(Future.succeededFuture(readyHandler.result()));
            } else {
                handler.handle(Future.failedFuture(readyHandler.cause()));
            }
        });
    }
```

Test code for mocking the dbService

```
    @Mock
    DBService dbService;

    @Captor
    private ArgumentCaptor<Handler<AsyncResult<JsonObject>>> resultHandlerCaptor;

    @Test
    public void test() {

        AsyncResult<JsonObject> result = Future.succeededFuture(new JsonObject().put("status", "success"));

        Mockito.verify(dbService).saveJobDetails(Mockito.any(JsonObject.class), resultHandlerCaptor.capture());
        Handler<AsyncResult<JsonObject>> handler = resultHandlerCaptor.getValue();
        handler.handle(result);
```

But when I am running this test getting an Exception

```
Wanted but not invoked:
dbService.saveJobDetails(
    <any io.vertx.core.json.JsonObject>,
    <Capturing argument>
);
    Actually, there were zero interactions with this mock.
```

Comment: Where is the `processAlert` method invoked in the test?

Comment: @tsegismont, I am calling it after handler.handler but before call come to processAlert it is failing